# Reorder columns with Materialize on phone

Tags: css, materialize

I'm using materialize framework and am trying to reorder the columns order in a phone view. I want to have the BUY BUTTON come before the CONTENT on mobile. Was trying pull and push but can't figure it out. Any help?

Thank you in advance.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
      <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s12 m6 push-m6 l7">CONTENT</div>
      <div class="col s12 m6 pull-m6 l2">BUY BUTTON</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you should organize your layout as mobile-first: the `BUY BUTTON` comes before by default, and in tablet screens or larger (`.m` or `.l` classes), you use `push` and `pull`:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m3 l3">
        <img src="">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 push-m6 m6 push-l7 l2">BUY BUTTON</div>
        <div class="col s12 pull-m6 m6 pull-l2 l7">CONTENT</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. So what if I wanted the columns to reorder only on mobile? Would only do push-s12 and pull-s12 correspondingly and get rid of the others push-m push-l ?

Comment: I tested with this approach, but it doesn't work, because `push-s12` will push `BUY BUTTON` out of screen, instead of stack above `CONTENT`.

Comment: How can I rearrange the columns only on mobile? That's really where I need it to change order.

Comment: With your current markup, there is no way to do this just with `push` and `pull`.

Comment: In my answer, I just changed the order between `BUY BUTTON` and `CONTENT` and added the correct classes. The effect is the same.

Comment: Hmm. Can I change the markup and rearrange order on mobile?
does push and pull not work with s columns?

Comment: Yes, `push` and `pull` works with `.s` columns. But, in your case, the `.s` columns fills the entire screen width(`.s12`).
 Therefore, with your markup, `CONTENT` always will be above `BUY BUTTON`. If your columns were `.s6`, `.push-s6` and `.pull-s6` would works perfectly. Sorry for my English.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116613/discussion-between-ken-ryan-and-allan-pereira).

Answer (score 0):

You can use table display CSS properties if you have few enough rows!

```
.row .l7{
  display: table-footer-group;
}
.row .l2{
  display: table-header-group;
}
```

Comment: Can I do it with materialize?